# Can Polymer Designer save a page as 'secret'?

Tags: polymer, polymer-designer-tool

It seems that when I save a page in Polymer Designer, it creates a public gist. Is there anyway to save it as 'secret' by default? I am running the designer locally.

Answer (score 1):

The `save()`/`update()` method post the gist to github. If you change the third param to `false`, it'll create a secret gist.

https://github.com/Polymer/designer/blob/master/elements/designer-element/designer-element.html#L404:L406

Please file a feature request if you'd like to see that baked into the designer: https://github.com/Polymer/designer/issues/new